# Bigcommerce stencil what is customLayouts used for?

Tags: bigcommerce

I noticed that after using the command `stencil init` to generate a `.stencil` file for a new stencil project, the generate file contains a `customLayouts` attribute. For example, the file might contain this:

```
{
  "normalStoreUrl": "http://www.my-store.com",
  "port": 3000,
  "username": "Stencil",
  "token": "11223344556677889900",
  "customLayouts": {
    "products": {},
    "search": {},
    "brands": {},
    "categories": {}
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain the purpose of this `customLayout` object and how it can be used?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't presently in use. It will be available for use to have customized templates per each of those types of pages once we have finished some engineering work. It is a placeholder at this time.

Comment: Great, thanks. Very much looking forward to that feature.